# What is the best practice to move/copy termset from global to local?

Tags: managed-metadata, export, import, term-store

I am using sharepoint 2010. I have 1 webapplication with many site collections. In one of my site collection I have some specific site with a list with a managed metadata column. I have setup this column looking to the global termstore. Now the end users would like to modify the terms inside this global termstore.

But I dont want to give them access to the central admin! I know it is possible to use a local termstore. But it is now to late because there are existing items with selected terms from the global termstore.

Is there some way to copy or move the whole termstore from global to local? But I would like to modify also the existing items which have a reference to the global termstore. So it is not only an export/import termsstore. I am a developer so powershell or a c# solutions are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the terms in the term store, there is a timer job "Taxonomy update scheduler" which takes care of updating the list items which reference that particular term. You can run the job manually to update the list items.

But do have a look at the below links.

1. [Terms and how to update TaxonomyHiddenList when the timer job was not able to update](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joerg_sinemus/archive/2011/03/03/terms-and-how-to-update-taxonomyhiddenlist-when-the-timer-job-was-not-able-to-update.aspx)
2. [Taxonomy Update Scheduler Timer Job](http://davidfrette.wordpress.com/2010/05/26/taxonomy-update-scheduler%C2%A0timer%C2%A0job/)

Comment: I think you dont understand my question. It is possible to create a termstore in central admin. This is the global term store. But it is also possible to create a term store in the site collection. This is the local term store. I would like to move a termstore from global to local.